# SQL Where clause and like query with letter and numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-like

I have a table with project numbers. The project numbers have different formats. I want to filter just the project numbers starting with `C` and 4 numbers (i.e. `C1234`) and with underscore 3 numbers (i.e. `C1234_123`). Other formats that i don´t want have a lot more numbers, points in between etc.

Can you help me with the `WHERE` clause?

```
WHERE
    Projectnumber LIKE 'C____%'
```

Here I also get the project numbers that have more than 4 numbers after the `C`. How to define a filter for this format  `C1234_123` ?

KR Julia

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What type of SQL server are you using?

Comment: You probably need to investigate REGEX functions

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description recommends, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: `LIKE 'C[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\_[0-9][0-9][0-9]' ESCAPE '\'` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I've made the assumption that, since you are asking about the `LIKE` clause you are asking about MS SQL Server. Please correct me if I'm wrong. It seemed more welcoming than voting to close.

Comment: i´m using azure data studio

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer with [a working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/BmXwq07q),

```
SELECT
            [ProjectNumber]
    FROM
            [Stuff]
    WHERE
            [ProjectNumber] LIKE 'C[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\_[0-9][0-9][0-9]' ESCAPE '\';
```

Note the use of the [`ESCAPE` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) to prevent the `_` being treated like a wildcard.